# My uefi is dull not accessible

Tags: windows

I recently deleted all my files from my hard drive to reinstall Windows 8.1 and when I turn on my laptop all it says is no bootable device, restart system, when I go into bios ,boot mode,uefi boot  is dull and not accessible how do I sort this,I no longer have Windows installed, but I do have a repair install disc.and have set my boot order to boot from DVD,but it still saysno bootable device my laptop is a Toshiba satellite

Comment: "uefi boot is dull" - Please edit your question, do not reply to this comment, it is not clear what you mean by the quoted statement.

Comment: I believe OP means the option is greyed out and not selectable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pressing **<kbd>F12</kbd>** at boot to load the Boot Menu and selecting the DVD drive from there?

- If it's still not listed as an option, the issue is likely the repair disk can't UEFI boot

  - **Resolution:** Create a UEFI compatible Windows Install USB

    1. Download the Windows 8.1 ISO [from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows8ISO)
    2. Use [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/) to create the bootable USB

       - Select the downloaded Windows Install ISO > Start
    3. Boot the USB
    4. Press **<kbd>F12</kbd>** at boot to load the Boot Menu
    5. Select the USB from the boot options

       - If there is more than one entry, choose the one that has "EFI" in the name